# string.split() returns extra items (functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
allUID = $("#allservices_"+categoryUID).attr("value").split(',');
```

applied to an element with

```
value="
1298698f-62a0-41da-9303-563e317f97a1,
75b79dc8-873f-4e80-9174-64e3bf0b7e7b,
7add7028-dd32-40cc-baa3-a8dbdfe36dc0,
0b136659-19e5-4b58-9b58-23a5ba7383fe,
73a6a712-4aae-4101-ad36-77feea188aad,
8f5d7f01-b854-4a6f-9cf6-cc6554835c8a,
f0c1d8dc-a96d-402a-b41b-74f753a4c313,
770d1178-8c17-4e9d-8a31-bff8a15097b3
"
```

returns this:

```
0   "1298698f-62a0-41da-9303-563e317f97a1"
1   "75b79dc8-873f-4e80-9174-64e3bf0b7e7b"
2   "7add7028-dd32-40cc-baa3-a8dbdfe36dc0"
3   "0b136659-19e5-4b58-9b58-23a5ba7383fe"
4   "73a6a712-4aae-4101-ad36-77feea188aad"
5   "8f5d7f01-b854-4a6f-9cf6-cc6554835c8a"
6   "f0c1d8dc-a96d-402a-b41b-74f753a4c313"
7   "770d1178-8c17-4e9d-8a31-bff8a15097b3"
contains    function()
removeDoubles   function()
reversed    function()
```

Where do these extra functions come from?

Comment: may i ask, how are you actually printing out each element of the array?

Comment: firebug in this case, in the code I'm returning values split from a couple of arrays, concatenated in a string html="uid: " + uid... etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It didn't happen for me](http://jsfiddle.net/AXAFw/).

Most likely, you are iterating over the resulting array with a `for ( in )`. Don't do that; use a normal `for` loop or jQuery's `each()`.

Somewhere else in your code probably augments the `Array` prototype and doesn't specify the properties to be non enumerable (only possible in latest JavaScript versions with `defineProperty()` and friends).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwksc/) (don't do this).

You should be using `val()`, rather than `attr('value')` too.

Comment: using for(i in ... ) and thanks for the tips.  Probably Plone and friends.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They're functions added to the array prototype (probably by a script you've included on the page). They're not part of the array as such, but they can be a problem when using for .. in to iterate over the array.

Extending the prototypes of built-in objects is not considered a good practice by most, so I would suggest replacing them if you can. Otherwise, use regular for loops over for .. in.

Answer (score 0):

Something else in your codebase is adding those functions to the Array instance. I don't know what, since both jQuery and Prototype don't add those functions.

Note some of the answers indicate that the array's prototype has been changed - that is probably not the case. Depending on how you are outputting them, some library has probably added those functions to the array itself, instead of its prototype (which is bad).

Comment: How do you know it's not the prototype? I think firebug will display an array like the above if the prototype has been augmented

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your array with this instead:

```
for (var i = 0, len = allUID.length; i < len; i++) {
   console.log(allUID[i]);
}
```

You will not see any of those extra properties when iterating over the array this way.

Those extra items come because you were iterating over the array with `for (i in allUID) {}` and that will pick up extra properties that have been added to the Array object by some framework or shim you are using.  You should never iterate over an array with `for (x in array)`.  Use that form only for iterating all the properties of an object.

Answer (score -1):

Probably from jQuery. I wouldn't be surprised if jQuery adds `Array.prototype.contains`, `Array.prototype.removeDoubles` and `Array.prototype.reversed`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't touch the `Array` prototype.